# Mercurial/Intellij9 hg4idea Error: cannot update with applied MQ patches, please use rebase

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

I am getting the following error when trying to update my project from Intellij 9 using hg4idea:

```
Error: cannot update with applied MQ patches, please use rebase
```

What does this mean? I have not created or applied any patches as far as I know. I can pull changes from my remote repository but cannot update the project from within Intellij.  I can call hg update from the command line and that works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://www.bitbucket.org/viacoban/hg4idea/issue/58/update-depends-on-mq-extension) of the hg4idea plug-in. The author suggests the following workaround:

> Enable mq extension in your .hgrc:

```
[extensions]
hgext.mq =
```

Comment: @johnrock: +1 to both of you... CrazyCoder is actually one of the JetBrains developer if I'm not mistaken, always great to see him help on here :)